# Swift 3 - Unable to execute a function

Tags: ios, swift, uisegmentedcontrol

Following is my code. I have also posted a screenshot.

Button_CustomSegmentValueChanged is a custom Segmented control which i have made. Its an individual button and is working fine but I want to run "Button_CustomSegmentValueChanged" function from inside "SwipedRight" function too, but i am unable to pass the correct switch value in order to do so. Need help with it.

Anyone?

```
import UIKit

class CredentialsViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var loginView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var signupView: UIView!

    var currentSelectedView = 0

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let swipeR = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(CredentialsViewController.SwipedRight(swipe:)))
        swipeR.direction = .right
        view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeR)

        let swipeL = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(CredentialsViewController.SwipedLeft(swipe:)))
        swipeL.direction = .left
        view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeL)

        //Hide view
        signupView.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: signupView.frame.size.width, y: 0)
    }

    @IBAction func Button_CustomSegmentValueChanged(_ sender: CustomSegmentedControl) {

        switch sender.selectedSegmentIndex {
        case 0:
            LoadLoginView()
            break

        case 1:
            LoadSignupView()
            break

        default:
            break
        }

    }

    func SwipedRight(swipe : UISwipeGestureRecognizer){
        if currentSelectedView == 1 {
            Button_CustomSegmentValueChanged(0)
            //LoadLoginView()
        }
    }

    func SwipedLeft(swipe : UISwipeGestureRecognizer){
        if currentSelectedView == 0 {
            //LoadSignupView()
        }

    }

    func LoadLoginView(){

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {
            self.signupView.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX : self.loginView.frame.size.width, y : 0)
            self.loginView.transform = .identity
            self.currentSelectedView = 0
        })
    }

    func LoadSignupView(){

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {
            self.signupView.transform = .identity
            self.loginView.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: self.loginView.frame.size.width, y: 0)
            self.currentSelectedView = 1
        })
    }


}
```

[Screenshot of my code and error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aj475.jpg)

Comment: Button_CustomSegmentValueChanged function accepts CustomSegmentedControl as parameter and you are trying to send Int to it

Comment: Hi, I understand what you are saying but can you show me the correct code of how it is to be done. The thing is that I have made a custom segmented controller with two options and I am using two views to toggle between two. When I tap on the segmented control, everything works fine. When i swipe, its working fine but the selector in segmented controller is not changing. And the reason is that it needs to be tapped to understand the switch. I want to replicate that by calling my tapped function from another function just o make it workt. Have a look at the video http://youtu.be/Z5CHq4-MeVo

Comment: Ok, can you show the code for CustomSegmentedControl ?

Comment: Yes sure.. There was one mistake which i fixed it.. Its "CredentialSegmented Controller" . Find the code here https://codeshare.io/5XN9bo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest to use the buttons array on CredentialSegmentedController to mimic the behaviour of change segment

1. Make an outlet from your custom segment control
2. Then modify your code using this segment control like below

   ```
   func SwipedRight(swipe : UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {

               if currentSelectedView == 1 {
                       //Button_CustomSegmentValueChanged(0)
                       //LoadLoginView()
                       let btn = customSegmentOutlet.buttons[0]
                       customSegmentOutlet.buttonTapped(btn)
               }
       }

       func SwipedLeft(swipe : UISwipeGestureRecognizer){
               if currentSelectedView == 0 {
                       //LoadSignupView()
                       let btn = customSegmentOutlet.buttons[1]
                       customSegmentOutlet.buttonTapped(btn)
               }

       }
   ```

Comment: Your code is working fine but my problem still persists. The thing is that I have made a custom segmented controller with two options and I am using two views to toggle between two. When I tap on the segmented control, everything works fine. When i swipe, its working fine but the selector in segmented controller is not changing. And the reason is that it needs to be tapped to understand the switch. I want to replicate that by calling my tapped function from another function just so as to switch the selector. 
Have a look at the video https://youtu.be/Z5CHq4-MeVo

Comment: @Biks I updated my answer according to you requirement , see if it helps you

Comment: AWESOME.. it worked.. phew!!! Thanks a lot.. its working perfectly now...

Comment: @Biks Glad I could help

Answer (score 1):

You are passing `Int` though the actual type required is `CustomSegmentedControl`. To simply solve this problem just create the `IBOutlet` for your `CustomSegmentedControl` and pass it as parameter to `Button_CustomSegmentValueChanged` method.

```
func SwipedRight(swipe : UISwipeGestureRecognizer){
    if currentSelectedView == 1 {
        customSegmentOutlet.selectedSegmentIndex = 0
        Button_CustomSegmentValueChanged(customSegmentOutlet)
        //LoadLoginView()
    }
}
```

Comment: I have made an outlet but what code do i write to call my Button function ? This doesnt work properly...  

func SwipedRight(swipe : UISwipeGestureRecognizer){
        if currentSelectedView == 1 {
            //Button_CustomSegmentValueChanged(0)
            customSegmentOutlet.selectedSegmentIndex = 1
            customSegmentOutlet.sendActions(for: .valueChanged)
            LoadLoginView()
        }
    }

Comment: nope.. its not working.. I have added my outlet inside the brackets but it doesnt accept it and gives error "Cannot convert value of type..."

` customSegmentOutlet.selectedSegmentIndex = 1
            Button_CustomSegmentValueChanged(customSegmentOutlet)
            LoadLoginView()`

Comment: cannot convert value of type 'CredentialSegmentedController!' to expected argument type 'CustomSegmentedControl'

Comment: @Biks I think you are not connecting the outlet right, please check again

Comment: Please create the IBOutlet for CustomSegmentedControl not CredentialSegmentedController because your IBAction refers CustomSegmentedControl.

Comment: I have made a custom class script for the segmented controller. I am not using the default one. Therefore it is CredentialSegmentedController (which is the name of my class script). Please check the image  http://imgur.com/a/sdBTh

Comment: Then what is "CustomSegmentedControl" in your Button_CustomSegmentValueChanged IBAction method ?

Comment: bro.. sorry.. there was a mistake in the connection. I fixed it. Its working. I am successful to replicated the button functionality but the solution i was trying to get is still not working. My segment control selector is still not changing. I guess its something else. I am trying to figure out the solution.

Comment: Ok. If you require any more help please comment here.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your `CustomSegmentedControl` is a subclass of `UISegmentedControl`, I have modified few lines of code

```
@IBAction func button_CustomSegmentValueChanged(_ sender: UISegmentedControl?) {
    // guard sender for nil before use
}
```

and when calling this

```
func swipedRight(swipe : UISwipeGestureRecognizer){
    if currentSelectedView == 1 {
       let seg = UISegmentedControl()
    seg.selectedSegmentIndex = 0
    Button_CustomSegmentValueChanged(seg)
    }
}
```

if `CustomSegmentedControl` is not subclass of `UISegmentedControl`, change it so.

Comment: Hi. Thanks. I have tried your method and its working. But the thing i was trying to achieve is still not happening. My view is changing but the segment controller selection is not changing. Please check the video and you will understand http://youtu.be/Z5CHq4-MeVo

Comment: Instead of creating new segmentcontroller, create an iboutlet for your existing one and use use it